# become or becomes

Tags: grammar, tenses

Is this correct? My first instinct says it should be *becomes/became* or *had become* but I am not sure, thanks.

> "... for what is and what is not art **become** blurred with the postmodern and modernist art practices."

Comment: Where did you find this sentence? Could you cite the author and where it was taken, please?

Comment: I think this is confusing as it stands - it's not immediately clear that the object that is becoming blurred is "what is and what is not art".  It would be clearer to say "The **distinction** between what is art and what is not art becomes blurred...", then it's obvious that the blurring is happening to the distinction between the two things.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's correct. There's two objects, 1) "what is art" & 2) "what is not", so it's a plural -- a singular *becomes* and plurals *become*.  Rephrased:

...for *art* and *not-art* become blurred..."

Answer (score 0):

Your first instinct is correct. In your sentence, "what is" and "what is not" are not two separate entities--they are inextricable. In fact, the unstated subject here is something like "the distinction" between what is and what isn't art--that is what has become blurred.